# Splitting a python data frame on column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python data frame in the format below

```
Timestamp1  Column1 Column2 Column3 Timestamp2   Column4 Column5 Column6  Column 7
01-01-2018   5.0     4.7     5.1      01-01-2018  5.8     7.9     6.7     8.1
01-02-2018   5.4     2.7     3.1      01-02-2018  1.8     1.9     2.7     8.1
```

I want to split it into two data frames such that I have two data frames like

```
Timestamp1 Column1 Column2 Column3
01-01-2018   5.0     4.7     5.1
01-02-2018   5.4     2.7     3.1

Timestamp2 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7
01-01-2018  5.8     7.9     6.7     8.1
01-02-2018  1.8     1.9     2.7     8.1
```

I tried to groupby, but was not able to get it to work. Column names can be different, so I am looking to split on the Timestamp and create two DF's

Any inputs on what I can use to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: So you're trying to split the dataframe according to the column types? I think the question could be improved. Also wher's the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I am trying to split on the column names which is Timestamp1 and Timestamp2. So all columns after Timestamp1 (but before Timestamp2) belong to one DF and all columns after Timestamp2 belong to the second DF.

Comment: But you have to be more specific, you say column names can be different. Can the amount of columns in between also be different? If not why not just use `.iloc`?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. Please put in the effort to provide sample data if you expect the effort of an answer.

Comment: Updated question to include sample data and that number of columns between are differing as shown above Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `df1 = df.loc[:,'Timestamp1':'Column3']` and `df2 = df.loc[:,'Timestamp2':'Column7']` should give you the desired results